# Stack install fails on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, iconv

I am trying to stack install (clean .stack directory and stack.yaml works on Linux) on MacOS Big Sur.

I get the following link errors:

_iconv_open not found (during the link phase)

MacOS does not seem to have the native libraries for iconv and the GNU libiconv has the function _libiconv_open but not _iconv_open.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/k9r2cy/workaround_for_haskell_woes_on_macos_11_big_sur/

Comment: Apologies for the late update. I had to build _iconv from source and install it. That allowed me to get past this error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [GHCUP](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/), worked like a charm for me. Just do

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | arch -x86_64 /bin/bash
```

and you're all set.